# send Massive push notification to GCM

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have to send Push Notifications with different messages for large number of devices(More than 10k devices per day).But sometimes its not receiving all of the devices.I set up a function `pushNotificationToUsers($heading,$message,$registraionids)` to send the push notification and I  am not sure about my method is correct ,if i am wrong please correct me.

```
function  pushNotificationToUsers($heading,$message,$registraionids){
        //array of registration ids in $registraionids         
        $key="xxxxxxxxxxx";
        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $fields = array(
                        'registration_ids'  =>,$registraionids,
                        'data'              => array( "message" => $message,"title"=>$heading,"soundname"=>"beep.wav" ),
                        );
        $headers = array(
                            'Authorization: key=' . $key,
                            'Content-Type: application/json'
                        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();
        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        }
```

I'm using php in my serverside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android,

The message size limit in GCM is 4 kbytes.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html#params

The message size limit in C2DM is 1024 bytes. (DEPRECATED)

https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#limitations

For iOS,

in iOS the size limit is 256 bytes, but since the introduction of iOS 8 has changed to 2kb!

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2626

Also, see below stuffs

After Google replaced C2DM with GCM, they took off all limits.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html#history

The only limits you run into the GCM documentation is this:

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#lifetime

I think this answer is enough clear for your question.

Comment: Thanks let me check that

Comment: Finally i found my problem from your answer.Actually GCm supports only at most 1000 devices at a time ,But what i am trying to send push to More than 1000 devices at a time Thats why sometimes devices cant recive the push.

Comment: Accept & up vote my answer. So other will refer it. This is SO.

Comment: One more question  if this parameter `delay_while_idle` is true what happend?

Comment: Android handles most of things by itself so just keep it to true, then it will handle delaying issues

Comment: Ok got it,can you edit your answer with my comments so others can easily understand it:)

Comment: So users always see comments, so this point is self explanatory. I don't think I need to add it. I think you have neither accepted my answer nor up voted it yet